# Is there a way to open a file residing on the server with an external program on a windows machine in C#?

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to open a file which is residing on the server on a windows machine. I tried using **System.Diagnostics** like below;

```
var FullPath = "https://localhost:44389/documents/Open Doc.xlsx";
Process.Start(FullPath);
```

Everytime I get an error saying the system can not find the specified file but if I take and paste that URL in the browser the file gets downloaded automatically meaning there is a file on the other end. Am I using **System.Diagnostics** the wrong way?

Comment: If the file is on local machine, you could use file protocol. Eg: file:///c:/folder/file.txt

Comment: You can't open such a file fully transparently (which is a good thing). You can instruct the system to launch the browser to handle the URL (`Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = fullPath, UseShellExecute = true })`), but that should not result in the file auto-opening if the browser is properly configured. If you actually want to download the file first, then open it, you should explicitly do so (through `WebClient.DownloadFile`, for example) then launch the local file.

Comment: You can download the file and work with a local copy or use file:///c:/folder/file.txt as nonameyet's coment.

Comment: @JeroenMostert So i can't open such a file fully transparent but it is theoretically possible? I have implemented your solution and it works, it takes me to the browser with the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code :

```
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("address")
    {
        UseShellExecute = true
    };
    process.Start();
```

If the address is on your Windows, it will run

And if it is an Internet address, it opens it in the browser